# Is there an R function for indexing in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, indexing, match

In R, I have two matrices A & B. Each matrix has two columns and more than 40,000 rows. If matrix A has (x,y) and matrix B has (y,z), I want to make a new matrix C which has (x,z).

For example,

```
> A
   UserID Name
 1    1    a
 2    2    b
 3    3    c
 4    4    a

> B
   Name Score
 1   c   100
 2   a   300
 3   b   200
 4   a   400
```

Than I want to have a matrix like below

```
> C
   UserID Score
 1    3    100
 2    1    350
 3    2    200
```

I used *for*, *if* but I think that is time-consuming.
Is there a function that works for it? What is the most efficient way to creat a new matrix like C?

*In advance, when Names are the same, I want to put median value of their score.
 Any helps for that?

Comment: You can `cbind` after extracting the corresponding columns from 'A' and 'B' (assuming that both matrix have the same number of rows). `C <- cbind(A[,x'], B[,'z'])`.  Did you meant that `x' and `y` are the column names or the elements?  If it is the elements, then `cbind(A[A=='x'], B[B=='z'])`, again assuming that you have equal number of 'x', 'z' in the two matrices.

Comment: Post a small example with specific values and show what you desire. At the moment it seems unclear what is meant by you wanting C that has (x,z). Most people would assume that A[x,y] is a single number determined by the values of x and y. What do you want to to be placed n the [y,z] position of C?Unless of course you just want `cbind( A[1,],B[2,])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up data:

```
A <- read.table(header=TRUE,
text="UserID Name
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    a")

B <- read.table(header=TRUE,
text="Name Score
c   100
a   300
b   200
a   400")
```

Aggregate data to replace scores with median by name and user IDs with the first user ID for each name:

```
B2 <- aggregate(Score~Name,B,median)
A2 <- aggregate(UserID~Name,A,head,1)
```

Now `merge`:

```
merge(A2,B2)

##  Name UserID Score
##1    a      1   350
##2    b      2   200
##3    c      3   100
```

These are not in the same order and retain the `Name` column but is otherwise what you requested ... `cbind()` is also workable if you're sure that everything is matching up correctly, but `merge` is safer.

If you wanted to aggregate a few Score columns at once:

```
B3 <- read.table(header=TRUE,
text="Name Score1 Score2 Score3
c   100 200 1
a   300 23  7
b   200 94  6
a   400 20  2")
```

you could try

```
B4 <- aggregate(B3[,-1],by=list(B3$Name),median)
names(B4)[1] <- "Name"
##   Name Score1 Score2 Score3
## 1    a    350   21.5    4.5
## 2    b    200   94.0    6.0
## 3    c    100  200.0    1.0
```

(see `?aggregate`: there is a formula interface for aggregating multiple columns at once with `cbind()`, but it's awkward if you have many variables to aggregate)

Comment: thank you for your help! then, how can i use 'aggregate' if there are many columns like score1, score2, score3, ..., score500?

Comment: that's really another question, but see my edited answer

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, you were a great help to me.